# Jaspersoft report won't run on container of a jasper report server

Tags: postgresql, docker, jasperserver

When running a report in jaspersoft studio it succesfully generates a report, with data adapted from a container of a postgres database on a ssh. the server is running as a jaspersoft for docker server on the same ssh.

however, after publishing the report to the jasperserver, when running the report on the server I get the following error trace:

```
com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.JSException: jsexception.error.creating.connection Arguments: at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.JdbcDataSourceService.createConnection(JdbcDataSourceService.java:64) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.BaseJdbcDataSource.setReportParameterValues(BaseJdbcDataSource.java:49) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.JdbcDataSourceService.setReportParameterValues(JdbcDataSourceService.java:69) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.fillReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:1823) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$ReportFill.runWithDataSource(EngineServiceImpl.java:1169) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$ReportFill.runReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:1051) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$ReportRunnable.run(EngineServiceImpl.java:946) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections. at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:207) at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64) at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:136) at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:29) at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:21) at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:31) at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24) at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393) at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267) at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664) at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247) at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverManagerConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverManagerConnectionFactory.java:75) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.JdbcDriverManagerConnectionFactory.createConnection(JdbcDriverManagerConnectionFactory.java:36) at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582) at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1148) at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.TibcoDriverManagerImpl.unlockConnection(TibcoDriverManagerImpl.java:68) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.JdbcDataSourceService.createConnection(JdbcDataSourceService.java:56) ... 9 more Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused) at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538) at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:60) at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:101) ... 26 more
```

Any ideas what the problem is? Is there a way to see what the remaining 26 errors are?

the connection of the containers in the ssh
[image: the connection of the containers in the ssh]

My machine is windows, but the ssh environment is Linux. I've used the jaspersoft for docker from https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/JS-Docker
and the datasource is from: https://github.com/docker-library/postgres

Comment: it  seems like on my dockerized jaspersoft server I can't get a connection to my dockerized datasource when trying to add datasources on the server itself. However if I run the standard jasperreport server service (from https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-server/releases ) and use the same parameters I can get a connection to my dockerised data source. So the problem must be in how I've made my dockerised jasperreport server.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a data source defined on the server.  When you deploy, you have to manually select this datasource during the deploy.